# Short Snorter Pacific Theatre

Tags: war, world, ww2-pacific-theater

I am a collector of World War ll memorabilia. I have one piece called a short snorter. They were done in both the pacific and european theatres. These were usually bomber crews or groups of men in battle that signed a piece of currency. Well sometimes these got very large and they would just keep on taping notes together and adding signatures. I have a piece of one because of the tape stain. I don't know if this is the right place to ask this, but I figured someone out there knows more than me about World War 2 in the pacific. I literally have spent hours trying to find the location of where this took place. I am into history anyway so it was time well spent trying to figure this out. So here is what it says, the question marks is the answer I am looking fo. "Taken From Jap Army Sgt. at ???????. May 3rd. Bumped off by Mike Council". If anybody can help me out that would be great. I do appreciate your time.

[Here is the note](http://www.anthonyscollectibles.com/Z/shortsnorter/Shortsnorter.jpg)

[image]

Comment: I suggest adding that image to the question using the image button. If the web site that it links to goes down or is removed then your question will become unreadable. **I am going to vote to close this question until that image is actually in the question, because otherwise the question will become unreadable if the link becomes invalid.**

Comment: Think I got My Answer......Thanks For Your Time.....Tony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the place is [**Washawng**](https://goo.gl/maps/xvAELaxRdXG2) in northern Burma/Myanmar, it's near [Ledo Road](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ledo_Road). The date could be 3rd May maybe 1944, but I cannot find the exact NCAC unit stationed there.

Comment: If you could put a bit more explanation as to your thought process behind this answer, it would be helpful, garner an upvote, and turn your answer from "I threw a dart at a map" into a "I believe this is it, oh, and here is why..."

Comment: @CGCampbell All the letters are readable on the picture. Although the name didn't ring any bell, I've put it to google and *voila*. I think the most fascinating and sneaky part was when I've clicked that I don't want the search term to be autocorrected to "washing".

Comment: Think I got My Answer......Thanks For Your Time.....Tony